# programmatically open an app in iOS

Tags: ios

I thought this was not possible but I have seen some apps do that: For example, if I receive a notification from Candy Crush in FB, it opens the Candy Crush Game. If I open a map in safari, I can open directly in Google Maps app. I think I have seen it in native apps, but I may be wrong.

So my question is whether this is possible. I have two apps, and I want the user to open the one inside of the other. So for instance, the one app has a button called "Open brother app"
and when I click it, it should open the Other app, if it is installed.

Both apps have the same company identifier, like : com.mycompany.ios.projectname.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible, using custom URL schemes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for apps supporting their own custom url schemes.
For more info have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18).